# Old debug keystore in Android

Tags: android, android-keystore

I have a sample hello world android  project in eclipse.
I want to see check the debug.keystore for that.
I am running the application in debug mode.
I checked the build path in eclipse---> preferences--->android--->build.
But when i check the debug.keystore file, it shows me the date modified for the file as 2012. 
so what is going wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing is wrong. The Android SDK generates a debug keystore once the first time you build an app and uses it for all apps built on the same machine, unless you specify explicitly a different debug keystore.